# Angular Material floating label and animations not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

My angular material components are working but **not displaying correctly**. I am using angular forms

`import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";`

The component is something like below:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" class="form-container">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input  formControlName="partNumber" matInput placeholder="Part Nr.">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button (click)="searchHandler()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Search</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

My inputs display as below:-
[image]

The button is also not raised as you can see above. Inspection of the form field gives this which involves translateY()

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-c5="" class="mat-input-container mat-form-field ng-tns-c7-1 mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-hide-placeholder mat-primary ng-valid mat-form-field-should-float ng-dirty ng-touched"><div class="mat-input-wrapper mat-form-field-wrapper"><div class="mat-input-flex mat-form-field-flex"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-input-infix mat-form-field-infix">
          <input _ngcontent-c5="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" formcontrolname="partNumber" matinput="" placeholder="Part Nr." ng-reflect-name="partNumber" ng-reflect-placeholder="Part Nr." id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
        <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper mat-input-placeholder-wrapper mat-form-field-placeholder-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="mat-form-field-label mat-input-placeholder mat-form-field-placeholder ng-tns-c7-1 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" for="mat-input-0" aria-owns="mat-input-0"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><!---->Part Nr.<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-input-underline mat-form-field-underline"><span class="mat-input-ripple mat-form-field-ripple"></span></div><div class="mat-input-subscript-wrapper mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-wrapper mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c7-1 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-spacer mat-form-field-hint-spacer"></div></div></div></div></mat-form-field>
```

While this is the way it should be displaying,
[image]

The versions of angular, material and cli I am using are as follows:
[image]

My CLI version is old, could it be an issue ?

In the app.module.ts, I have imported

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import {
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatGridListModule
} from "@angular/material";
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { MatSelectModule } from "@angular/material/select";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
```

and also added them to the `NgModule` decorator imports. What could be wrong ? It is a legacy project though having many other components. I am wondering if some other component could be interfering with these material components?

Comment: From my experience in angular, try using any similitar funcionallity with bootstrap or if you can use with css. Some angular components don't work and the version doesn't help

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Andres2142 no errors in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Automated Material Installation

Try installing Material using this command:

> ng add @angular/material

This way you will be prompted during the installation to configure some important things, like:

- BrowserAnimationsModule / (NoopAnimationsModule)
- Links and classes in index.html
- Import one of the default styles in `styles.scss`

Maybe also check out the [Official Documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

*I will leave this here for anyone not using older Angular/Material versions that do not support this yet.*

### Manual Installation (Material 5)

- npm i @angular/material@5.2.5

  - Also install missing depencency: CDK
- npm i @angular/animations@5.2.11
- Import BrowserAnimationsModule in your app.module.ts
- Import the Material component modules in your app.module.ts
- Add a default import to styles.css

Full guide:
[Here](https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-ready-2j1syg?file=app/app.component.html) I made as reference for you to compare with your project.

Comment: `ng add` doesn't come with the old version of my angular cli. I am not willing to update my cli version because it might then break other things as it is a legacy codebase.

Comment: @PrateekBhuwania Ah, I didn't notice the `angular-material-5` label. I updated my answer and added an example Stackblitz for you. You should really think about updating your application tho'. Try running `npm audit` in the project and you'll see why.

Comment: Thank you @H3AR7B3A7. To find the issue, I used your project as a base and then slowly added my org's files and folders to convert it to my current project. I had to take the long path because I tried everything earlier like installing compatible versions of node, cli, angular and other packages. The issue I found was that one of my org's theme overrode some of the functionality of the material theme. I didn't know it as I am new to the org and project.